# ItemView display animation with wrong position in RecyclerView when fast scrolling

Tags: android, adapter, android-recyclerview

I am building a chat user interface with recyclerView,and it allows three kinds of message:  `textMessage`  `voiceMessage` `photoMessage`.
For `voiceMessageItem` is playing,I intent to make its `voiceMessageIcon`(animation-list drwable resource)start playing animation.
But when I fast scroll the recyclerView,the `voiceMessageItem` goes to the wrong position.  [image]
adapter onBindViewHolder:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
       holder.getTextView(R.id.in_voice_content_iv).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (MediaPlayerUtils.isPlaying()) {
                        MediaPlayerUtils.stopPlaying();
                        playMessage(msg);
                    } else {
                        playMessage(msg);
                    }
                    ((AnimationDrawable) holder.getTextView(R.id.in_voice_content_iv).getCompoundDrawables()[0]).start();
                    SharedPreferencesUtils.put(context, "itemState", msg.getId());
                }
            }); 

}
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Where are you setting back to default value when view is recycled?

Comment: @Selvin I set it in sharedpreference

Comment: @Selvin I override in `onViewRecycled `

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have already solved this issue. But in case you haven't, try setting it to the appropriate value(textMessage, voiceMessage or photoMessage) depending on isPlaying() in onBindViewHolder even outside your onClick function.

Answer (score 0):

shouldn't you somehow use the position parameter?
how do you know how to get the correct item from the adapter?

use the position but not inside the listener -- as there you should use

```
holder.getAdapterPosition();
```